# How would I check if the data inputted is in the table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Making a very simple login and password, how would i Check to see if the username & password are in the database. I have a query that should select all the usernames/password that match usernames/password, but i do not know how to access the data selected
The query is as follows:`string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='"+ Username +"' AND password='"+ Password +"'";`

Comment: I hope nobody's user name is [Robert'); DROP TABLE user; --](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as i do not know what to put hence the question

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli

Answer (score 0):

i would say that you could make List or array, and then set string that will be the password or login and then loob through string Array (or list) and check if anything there is equal to the password or login string, something like this Array version)

```
public string Login;
public string Password;
public string[] Logins;
public string[] Passwords;

private void Start() {

    Logins = new string[<Length of the Array>];
    Passwords = new string[<Length of the Array>];

    CheckPasswordAndLogin();

}

public void CheckPasswordAndLogin() {

    for(int i = 0; i < Logins.Length; i++) {

        if(Logins[i] == Login) {

            //do something

        } else {

            //print error

        }

    }

}
```

and here is the List version:

```
public string Login;
public string Passwords;

public List<string> Logins = new List<string>();
public List<string> Passwords = new List<string>();

private void Start() {

    CheckPasswordAndLogin()

}

public void CheckPasswordAndLogin() {

    foreach(string login in Logins) {

        if(login == Login) {

            //log in

        } else {

            //print error or something

        }

    }

}
```

and then you can just repeat the same thing but with Passwords